How can I open a file if I imported "open" from the AppOpener library?
So I have this code:
import time
import pyautogui
from AppOpener import open
open("bloc de notas")
time.sleep(0.5)
with open('sometext.txt', 'r') as file:
    texto = file.read()
pyautogui.typewrite(texto)

where I want to copy the text frome "sometext.txt" but I get an error because it can´t find it in the list of applications:
SOMETEXT TXT NOT FOUND... TYPE (LS) for list of applications.
I thought using the words "as file" would be enough. But I get the error. Is there a way around this? Also sometext.txt is on the same folder that the code.

A name can only ever mean one thing at a time. Python can't consider the context to decide on a different meaning, and anyway every time you re-assign the name, the old meaning is forgotten. By writing from AppOpener import open, you cause open to mean whatever AppOpener says it means, and so it stops having the built-in meaning. Please see the linked duplicates for details.

Normally one would keep the namespace: import AppOpener and then AppOpener.open when you want to use it. It makes the code more readable in the long run. But open is also in builtins, so import builtins and then builtins.open.
